# Rails - how to save existing record and apply update to a copy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a webpage that tracks budgets containing a LOT of variables, stored in 40+ columns. Over time, adjustments are made to these budgets, but I need to be able to track changes over time and year to year. I tried adding a private method to my model that should create a duplicate of the existing record triggered by a **:before_update** callback. However, it's not working. The update changes the existing record, and the original is not preserved at all.

**Model:**

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_update :copy_budget

  private

  def copy_budget
    @budget = Budget.find(params[:id])
    @budget.dup
    @budget.save
  end
end
```

I'm still learning rails, (this is in Rails 4) and I think this would have been the best way to do this. If not, is there a better way to set the form to ALWAYS post a new record instead of routing to update if a record already exists?

Currently the form_for line looks like this:

`<%= form_for(@budget) do |f| %>`

Everything works as it should, with the exception of the duplication not happening. What am I missing? Is it possible the .dup function is also duplicating the :id? This is assigned by auto-increment in the MySQL db I an using, so if .dup is copying EVERYTHING, is there a way to copy all of the data except the :id into a new record?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Your best bet would be to use a library built for auditing changes like [`audited`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/audited) or [`paper_trail`](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [*dup*](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Core.html#method-i-dup) method returns the new object without an id, it doesn't update it in place. Since your `copy_budget` method is already an instance method on `Budget`, you also would not need to (and you wouldn't even be able to, since `params` aren't accessible in models) look up the budget by id and instead could just use the current instance (self). So the following changed would fix the `copy_budget` method for you, but you are still copying an already modified object, just before it gets saved to the database

```
def copy_budget
  copy_of_budget = self.dup
  copy_of_budget.save
end
```

it would work the way you're expecting it to work. However, you aren't linking the copy in anyway to the current version of the Budget (no way to tell Budget id = 1 is an older version of Budget id = 2). I'd recommend taking a look at a gem such as [PaperTrail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail) (I'm sure there are lots of others if that one doesn't suit your needs) which has already thought through a lot of the problems and features with keeping a history of record changed.

Comment: Maybe also touch on the fact that the OP has `#copy_budget` defined in `Budget` model. Where `params` is not accessible and `@budget` could just be `self`. Also the fact that `duping` the current object does not indicate the `#changes` so the dup will have no `id` or timestamps but will reflect the changed object (I believe).

Comment: Simple Lime, I tried changing the copy_budget method to match your suggestions, there still is nothing getting duplicated in my model. The existing record has the changes applied, but no copy is created.

Comment: What version of rails are you in and how are you checking if it worked? Just created a test app in rails 5.1.2 and it's creating a new Budget for me every time, no matter how I update the record. Though as mentioned in my answer, both the records are identical except for the id, because you're copying a record with changes already made to it, so you'd need to update your code to copy the old version ([changes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html#method-i-changes) may help you there. I still recommend checking out some gems that have already done this though

Answer (score 0):

While this question is a bit dated, the same requirement came up for me recently.  In the `before_update` method, you need to duplicate the existing record.  But, you don't really have it because `self` contains the updated information.  You will need to pull the original record and duplicate it.

You are saving the old `record` with a new `id`.  It will be wise to remember the original primary record's `id`.  So, you add a new column named `p_id`.  Then, the following works:

```rb
before_update :archive_record

def archive_record
  prev = Record.find(self.id)
  arch = prev.dup
  arch.p_id = self.id          ## arch.p_id = arch.id works just as well
  arch.save
end
```

Your primary records will have `p_id` as `nil`.  You can define a matching scope for this.  Primary records will always be current and their `id` remains fixed.  Each duplicate (history/archive record) will remember the id of its primary record.

There are all sorts of other trade-offs in this approach.  But this will keep track of all the versions of `record` in your app.